# How do I fix my click not always being accurate

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I am relatively new to coding but I am in the process of learning python, so that I can hopefully code a checkout bot for bestbuy canada to help me get my hands on one of the new rtx cards for my new pc. I am currently running python 3.9 and writing the code in IDLE.
The issue I am encountering is with this line of code:

```
# find add to cart button
try:
    atcBtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".addToCartButton_1DQ8z"))
    )
except:
    driver.refresh()
    continue

print("Add to cart button found")

try:
    # add to cart
    atcBtn.click()

    print("Added to cart")

    # go to cart and begin checkout as guest
    driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/basket")
```

The code is supposed to locate and click on the Add to Cart button, it dose this occasionally and actually adds the item to cart but the majority of the time it reads as having clicked on the button but dosent actually do it. If there is anything I can do to fix this please let me know as I am strugging to figure out what is wrong.
Any help/suggestions are hugely appreciated :D

Comment: Where can I find the `add to cart` button?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help if the error is an element not clickable or something like that.

```
 from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains 
 actions = ActionsChains(driver)
 item_to_click = driver.find_element_by_id('the id of the element you want to click on')
 actions.click(item_to_click)
 actions.preform()
```

that should do it. your code is too complicted just for a single click.
most of the times this would work:

```
 driver.find_element_by_id('id').click()
```

Comment: Ill give that a shot thanks, the only reason I had it set up the way I did was because I wanted the bot to click the button as fast as possible withouit having to reload the page

Comment: @CrazyPurpleMonkey did you ever get your code working? would you be willing to throw it up here or on a github page I could check out please :)